# C - Как посимвольно обработать строку, введённую с клавиатуры?

Tags: c, массивы, строки

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char str_[100];

void stroka(char *s, int l);

void main()
{   int a;
    gets(str_);
    a = strlen(str_);
    stroka(str_, a);
}

void stroka(char *str1, int a1)
{ int i, count = 0;
  char result;
    for (i = 0; i <= a1; i++)
        {
            if (strl[i] == ' ')
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                        {
                            printf("Error. Spacebar can't be first digit ");
                        }
                    break;
                }
            if (isdigit(strl[i]))
                {
                    count++;
                    if (count < 3)
                        {
                            result += strl[i];
                        }
                }
            else
                {
                    count = 0;
                    result += strl[i];
                }
        }
}
```

В строке `if (strl[i] == ' ')` выводится ошибка 'strl' undeclared (first use in this function).

Как я понимаю, это ошибка в том, что цикл не знает, что это за массив. Но я же его передаю. Подскажите.

Comment: Где именно вы его передаёте? В функцию stroka поступает *str1(один), а внутри используется strl(эль).

Comment: да, я понял уже, спасибо за объяснение. Пишу в code blocks, там 1 и l схожи. Невнимательность сыграла злую шутку. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что передаёте `str1`, а не `strl`. Посмотрите на саму ошибку повнимательнее.

Надо или передавать `void stroka(char *strl, int a1)`, или `strl` везде заменить на `str1`

Comment: боже, я перепроверил все логические ошибки, а такую простецкую вещь не смог.
спасибо, во всём виновата моя невнимательность и шрифт codeblocks, в которой l и 1 практически неотличимы